# Creating a report in another tab based on matching result

Tags: excel, vba

I'm very new to VBA and I have a fairly complicated matrix that I'm attempting to create a search tab for. Please help!

I've created a simplified version, which you can access using the link below.

https://drive.google.com/open?id=1awHkMyHrh4uirhmo1T1DU10K9ckDCwE7

**Here's the idea:**

- When a name is entered in the field on the second sheet, the matching
  name is located in the first column of first sheet.
- The information (training name, number, version) for the incomplete trainings
  (those with an 'N' in the row with the matching name) is copied to
  the second tab with a transposed layout.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
Sub test()
    Dim Ws As Worksheet
    Dim toWs As Worksheet
    Dim vDB, vR()
    Dim i As Long, j As Integer
    Dim n As Integer
    Dim sName As String

    Set Ws = Sheets("Sheet1")
    Set toWs = Sheets("Sheet2")

    vDB = Ws.Range("b3").CurrentRegion
    With toWs
        sName = .Range("c2")
        For i = 4 To UBound(vDB, 1)
            If vDB(i, 1) = sName Then
                For j = 3 To 5
                    If vDB(i, j) = "N" Then
                        n = n + 1
                        ReDim Preserve vR(1 To 4, 1 To n)
                        vR(1, n) = vDB(1, j)
                        vR(2, n) = vDB(2, j)
                        vR(3, n) = vDB(3, j)
                        vR(4, n) = vDB(i, j)
                    End If
                Next j
            End If
        Next i
        If n > 0 Then
            With .Range("b4")
                .CurrentRegion.Clear
                .Resize(n, 4) = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(vR)
                With .CurrentRegion
                    .Borders.LineStyle = xlContinuous
                    .CurrentRegion.BorderAround Weight:=xlMedium
                    .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
                End With
                .Resize(n, 3).Interior.Color = 14277081
                .Resize(n, 3).BorderAround Weight:=xlMedium
            End With
        Else
            .Range("a4").CurrentRegion.Clear
            MsgBox "No Data"
        End If
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you! I'm getting a type mismatch on For i = 4 To UBound(vDB, 1)

Comment: @femwill, In my test works fine. You need to select a range of data that you want to change. Base your cell on a series of data.  ~~>  vDB = Ws.Range("b6").CurrentRegion